# How to make Round Squre Image Asset Icon in adroid studio

Tags: android, android-icons

Hi I am try to make Squricle or Round Squre Icon In image Asset but can't make .
Any one please help me

Answer (score 1):

create shape like this and make round using corner radius

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">


    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:radius="40dp" />

          <!--<solid
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />-->



</shape>
```